# Naudio - Disposing WaveIn / WaveOut

Tags: naudio

Is it safe to dispose `WaveIn` and `WaveOut` right after stopping them, and not in the event handlers of `WaveIn.RecordingStopped` and `WaveOut.PlaybackStopped`? Like this:

```
MyWaveIn.StopRecording();
MyWaveIn.Dispose();
MyWaveIn = null;
```

And:

```
MyWaveOut.Stop();
MyWaveOut.Dispose();
MyWaveOut = null;
```

If `WaveIn` / `WaveOut` stopped due to an error, or if the playback stopped because the file being played reach its end, I will dispose them in the event handlers. I'm asking just about the situation where I stop them explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally recommend disposing in the `PlaybackStopped` event handler, but most soundcard drivers seem perfectly happy with you disposing while playback or recording is still in progress (under the hood you're just calling the `waveOutClose` or `waveInClose` windows API).